# Frame buffer texture data update using DirectX

Tags: visual-c++, directx, textures, directx-11, hololens

I am trying my hands on Direct X 11 template in VS 2015 in VC++. I am using:
**D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE** Resource and MAP and UNMAP to update texture.
Now i have a separate file in my project where i am reading pixels and need to upload it to this texture.

I am using a struct to hold the texture data :

```
struct Frames{
int text_Width;
int text_height;
unsigned int text_Sz;
unsigned char* text_Data; };
```

Want to know how can i use this struct from a separate file to upload the texture data in my Direct X based Spinning Cube file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what format the data is, which is essential to knowing how to do this, but let's assume your `text_Data` points to an array of R8G8B8A8 data (i.e. each pixel is 32-bits with 8-bits each of Red, Green, Blue, and Alpha in that order from LSB to MSB). If so, it would look like:

```
Frames f = ...; // your structure 

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc = {};
desc.Width = UINT(f.text_Width);
desc.Height = UINT(f.text_height);
desc.MipLevels = desc.ArraySize = 1;
desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
desc.MiscFlags = 0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData = {};
initData.pSysMem = f.text_Data;
initData.SysMemPitch = UINT( 4 * f.text_width );
initData.SysMemSlicePitch = UINT( text_Sz );

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> pTexture;
HRESULT hr = d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D( &desc, &initData, &pTexture );
if (FAILED(hr))
    ...
```

Note this is covered on MSDN in the [How to use Direct3D 11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404569.aspx) topics, although the sample code style there is a little dated.

> Take a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and the [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) in particular. There's no reason to write your own loader when you can just `DDSTextureLoader` or `WICTextureLoader`.